# Mac OSX Lion: Reverse scroll on only mouse

Tags: mac, macos

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I set a different scrolling direction for mouse and trackpad in Lion?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/17966/how-can-i-set-a-different-scrolling-direction-for-mouse-and-trackpad-in-lion)

Is there possible to disable reverse scroll only on the mouse, and not when using the touch on my macbook.

Answer (score 0):

You could install a third party mouse prefpane or driver that lets you configure your mouse(s); [USB Overdrive](http://www.usboverdrive.com/USBOverdrive/Information.html) is one.