# Is it possible to automatically switch between scrolling?

Tags: mouse, trackpad, macos

I have a Logitech mouse that I use with my Macbook Pro.
I've been using it for a week now and I just CAN'T get used to the inverse scrolling direction on the mouse wheel. I decided to change it in my System Preferences since I can't automatically change it in the Logitech mouse software.

Sometimes when I can't use my mouse, I have to use my trackpad, and getting used to the "natural" scrolling is annoying.

Is there a way to make my Macbook automatically change the scrolling direction depending if I'm using my trackpad and my mouse?

Does anyone know if there's a script that I can use? I'm OK with just using it on my Dock. I already have a script for clearing my clipboard.

Comment: Which mouse is it? Perhaps more importantly, what software came with it? I've got a Logitech trackpad (and keyboard) and the software for them is "Logitech Options" - if you've installed it it'll appear in the bottom row of your Preferences. My trackpad has an option for "Scroll direction" - your mouse may, too. Note that I also have a Logitech trackball that *doesn't* use Logitech Options, so YMMV! (Responded as a comment because (a) this isn't really an answer, and (b) I don't know yet if it's useful info).

Answer (score 5):

When I can, I prefer my own home-rolled solution to adding more third party software and if you want to toggle the *state* of the **Scroll direction: natural** *checkbox*, which is a *global setting* and found under both the **Mouse** and the **Trackpad** preference panes, under **Point & Click**, in **System Preferences**, you can use the following AppleScript *code* saved as an *application* and then place it in the **Dock** via *drag and drop*.

- Note that because this is a *global setting*, it doesn't matter whether you check/uncheck from either the **Mouse** or the **Trackpad** preference panes and as such I've coded this to target the **Mouse** preference pane as it should have the *checkbox* even when a **Trackpad** isn't present.

I saved the following AppleScript *code* in **Script Editor** as an application named: **Toggle Natural Scrolling**

---

```
on run
    try
        tell application "System Preferences"
            set current pane to pane "com.apple.preference.mouse"
            activate
        end tell
        tell application "System Events" to tell process "System Preferences"
            tell radio button 1 of tab group 1 of window 1 to if value is 0 then click
            set cbValue to value of (click checkbox 1 of tab group 1 of window 1)
        end tell
        tell application "System Preferences" to quit
        tell me
            activate
            if cbValue is equal to 1 then
                -- display dialog "Natural scrolling is now active." buttons {"OK"} default button 1 with title "Toggle Natural Scrolling" giving up after 3
                display notification "Natural scrolling is now active."
            else
                -- display dialog "Natural scrolling is no longer active." buttons {"OK"} default button 1 with title "Toggle Natural Scrolling" giving up after 3
                display notification "Natural scrolling is no longer active."
            end if
        end tell
    on error eStr number eNum
        activate
        display dialog eStr & " number " & eNum buttons {"OK"} default button 1 with title "Toggle Natural Scrolling" with icon caution
    end try
end run
```

---

As presently coded the `display dialog` *commands* are commented out and are there because I originally wrote this under OS X 10.8.5, which doesn't support the `display notification` *command*, however I've also tested (some of the *code*) under macOS 10.12 and why the `display notification` *command* is being used. I've left both in the *code* since I do not know which version you're running and you can comment/uncomment accordingly.

Under OS X 10.9 and later, you will need to add the **Toggle Natural Scrolling** to Accessibility, under Privacy, under Security & Privacy preferences, in System Preferences. If you don’t, you’ll get the following error when running it:

> Toggle Natural Scrolling is not allowed assistive access. number -1719

Comment: Every time you change and save the file, you'll need to uncheck and re-check the entry under Accessibility for it to work.

Comment: @Daniel, Yes, the is normal expected behavior and SOP as a safety measure against running unauthorized _code_.

Comment: Yes, I realize this might be intended behavior, however it is not obvious. The box is still checked, but it is not respected since it is for a previous version of the script. I added my comment in case someone was scratching their heads as to why their changes weren't working.

Comment: I got this from your script: `System Settings got an error: AppleEvent handler failed. number -10000`

Answer (score 2):

I made an app to solve this issue in as simple as a way as possible! It's open source and less than 300 lines of swift code, if you are paranoid you can check it out and build it yourself.

https://github.com/ther0n/UnnaturalScrollWheels

Answer (score 0):

In the case of using an Apple Magic Mouse with my MacBook Pro I found that when I changed the setting for 'Scrolling Direction: Natural' by turning it off in the Mouse settings, that the same setting is also changed in the Trackpad settings.

Searching on this site I found [this post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/116617/how-to-separate-mouse-and-trackpad-settings) which provides a link to software which allows you to set separate settings for your mouse and trackpad.