# Toggle natural scrolling

Tags: applescript, automator

On macOS 13, I'm trying to:

1. Open the **Trackpad** preferences pane
2. Toggle over to the **Scroll and Zoom** tab
3. Toggle the **Natural scrolling** to the opposite of whatever it currently is

I don't care how I achieve it (Automator / shell script etc.), as long as it's natively in macOS (no third-party apps).

I have the first part:

```
open /System/Library/PreferencePanes/Trackpad.prefPane
```

Any idea on how to achieve the rest?

The documentation for Automator seems non-existent!

Comment: @Thinkr The old Q might need a new answer for macOS 13 though.

Comment: @nohillside Yeah. Probably. I'll see if I can answer - I doubt so though. Also, I've seen some other possible duplicates.

Comment: @nohillside Possible duplicates: https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/264691 and https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/264742