# How can I toggle Natural Scrolling in macOS Sonoma 14.0 without using third-party software?

Tags: mouse, script, trackpad, settings, macos

I want to toggle natural scrolling without using third-party software, as is done [here](https://ziga.dev/posts/macos-scroll-reverse/) and [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/264742/509872). However, these scripts no longer work in macOS Sonoma 14.0 because the layout of the System Settings application has changed.

This is not a duplicate of similar older questions. Those questions have solutions that work on older versions of macOS, but that do not work on Sonoma. Please do not mark this question as a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of trial and error, I finally managed to make a script that works in Sonoma. Try this:

```
-- Open trackpad settings
open location "x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.Trackpad-Settings.extension"

tell application "System Events"
    tell application process "System Settings"
        tell group 1 of group 2 of splitter group 1 of group 1 of window 1
            
            -- Select "Scroll & Zoom" tab
            repeat until tab group 1 exists
                delay 0
            end repeat
            tell tab group 1
                click radio button 2
            end tell
            
            -- Toggle "Natural scrolling" flag
            repeat until group 1 of scroll area 1 exists
                delay 0
            end repeat
            tell group 1 of scroll area 1
                click checkbox 1
            end tell
            
            delay 0.1
            tell application "System Settings"
                quit
            end tell
            
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you for taking the time to share this.

Answer (score 0):

That's the problem with GUI scripting that automates human actions moving the pointer, rather than scripting the actual command required. If the UI changes, the script breaks.

Have you tried using:

```
defaults write -g com.apple.swipescrolldirection -bool NO
```

in the Terminal? You'll need to log out and back in to see the result.

Comment: Unfortunately logging out and logging back in every time I plug in a mouse defeats the purpose of automating this: saving time.