# How to separate mouse and trackpad scroll settings using terminal?

Tags: mouse, trackpad

Currently the scroll direction for mouse is bound to trackpad. Is there any way to unlink them **without downloading any third party apps**?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to separate "mouse" and "trackpad" settings?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/116617/how-to-separate-mouse-and-trackpad-settings)

Comment: @Nimesh Neema, Thie is not a duplicate because of "**without downloading any third party apps**" and your possible duplicate is nothing but third party apps! That said though, I think the only way possible is with a third party app.

Comment: If you don’t get any answers after a while, consider adding this to explain why third-party app is not desirable and work a third-party app might mean. Perhaps you are looking to automate this or script this or write your own third party app?

Comment: @user3439894 you will likely get a lot of votes if you answer this is not programmed and although the op doesn’t want to install apps, the practical solution for most people wanting this is the linked question

Comment: I am unable to download third party apps due to bureaucratic reasons. Is there any way to emulate the third party apps through other means, e.g. perhaps terminal commands?

Comment: @bmike, You said "you will likely get a lot of votes if you answer this is not programmed", sorry but I don't understand what you're saying. As to the rest of your comment to me, well what most people want is irrelevant in this particular case as the OP explicitly stated "**without downloading any third party apps**" so while I don't disagree with your point, nonetheless I fail to see why it was made in this use case.

Comment: t.c, Unfortunately how Apple has programmed this, there is not a native terminal command, that I know of, to separate the scrolling direction of the mouse and trackpad as they both use the same setting. The reason third-party apps work for this, generally speaking, is because they watch the event stream and intercept the target events to then have their app control the situation. If you can't install a third-party app then if you have Xcode installed, maybe you can use the source code from [Scroll Reverser](https://pilotmoon.com/scrollreverser/) to build you own version of it to install.

Comment: @user3439894 ahh I see.. thanks a lot for the explanation :)