# Using a Magic Trackpad 2 upside down

Tags: magic-trackpad

The Magic Trackpad 2 seems nice... except it's upside down. The tall part of the device should be closest to the user, not furthest. As built, it's a finger torture machine! How can I switch the default orientation 180º?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reverse Magic Trackpad (turn 180°)](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/121499/reverse-magic-trackpad-turn-180)

Answer (score 5):

Sebastian, there are some great news for you:

As of today, you can use your Magic Trackpad 2 upside-down with BetterTouchTool:

> BetterTouchTool 1.93 (October, 23, 2016)
>
> - Fixed some little Sierra issues regarding keyboard shortcuts
> - You can now choose whether a normal mouse button should trigger on mouse-down or on mouse-up (click the little gear icon left to the
>     mouse button selection)
> - You can now repeat an action while a mouse button is pressed (click the little gear icon left to the mouse button selection).
> - Added option to mirror the **Magic Trackpad orientation for upside-down usage**. It's in the advanced trackpad options => General

See [BetterTouchTool Homepage.](https://www.boastr.net/downloads/)