# Magic Trackpad 2 - Orientation (Rotate by 180)

Tags: defaults, magic-trackpad

I've done enough googling and found the solution of:

- writing defaults to com.apple.trackpad.orientation
- writing defaults to com.MultitouchSupport.

- reboot of the trackpad.

Neither of them work to rotate it for 180.

Is there any other solution than third party software? (that somehow does manage to change the orientation).

Thank you very much.

Comment: What is it you're trying to achieve, and why? You want upward movements of your fingers to move the pointer down?  Or are you talking about "Natural scrolling" direction? Also, you say "reboot the mouse", but the heading says Magic Trackpad. Which is it? And what OS?

Comment: Hello.
I want the orientation of the magic trackpad (external trackpad) be rotated for 180 (to use it with the slope downwards).

Rebooting the mouse by shutting it off and on using the switch on the mouse.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reverse Magic Trackpad (turn 180°)](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/121499/reverse-magic-trackpad-turn-180)

Answer (score 0):

There are already two questions which discuss this need:

[Reverse Magic Trackpad (turn 180°)](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/121499/reverse-magic-trackpad-turn-180)

[Using a Magic Trackpad 2 upside down](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/254156/using-a-magic-trackpad-2-upside-down)

If the preference keys suggested there no longer work, then I suspect the answer is "No" - the only solution is to use [BetterTouchTool](https://folivora.ai), which can be purchased for $9.

Comment: How does that tool do it? If you quit the app, it still is inverted, so I'd assume there still are some properties left that can be changed?

Comment: You'd need to ask the developers; if they're willing to tell you. Or you could try combing through Apple's API documentation, to see if there's some programmatic way to affect the rotation.

Comment: Yeah fair enough.
I doubt they'd be willing to tell me, but it is indeed worth a try.

I did attempt to see if the software changes any of the "defaults" properties on the machine, but did not notice any differences.

I'll reply back if / when I find any new information. Thank you